# Understanding Interface Builder - Swift

Tags: class, swift, interface-builder, nspopupbutton

Alright, so I'm not trying to do a whole lot at this stage. I have created a Swift class that is supposed to update an NSPopUpButton with a list of available serial ports. I've finalized the code for retrieving the list of ports and created a window in interface builder including the popup button but I can't get the two to work together.

I've tried editing the 'custom class' field of the window to 'Serial' to match my class but that gives me errors in the debugging window when running the program. I've tried to link the two with the command+drag tool with varying success but no matter what I try, I can't manage to update the button of my program.

How should I be doing this? What am I missing?

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class Serial {

    init() {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var serialListPullDown: NSPopUpButton!

    func refreshSerialList(defaultprompt: String) {

        //Initialize ORSSerialPortManager
        let portManager : ORSSerialPortManager = ORSSerialPortManager.sharedSerialPortManager()
         var availablePorts : NSArray = portManager.availablePorts

        //Erase entries from popup field
        serialListPullDown?.removeAllItems()

        for port in availablePorts as [ORSSerialPort] {
            //Add ports to popup window

            var Port = "\(port.path)"

            serialListPullDown?.insertText(Port)

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Interface Builder Window]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Serial to a subclass of UIViewController (assuming that That window is a UIViewController)

```
class Serial: UIViewController {}
```

then change the Custom class to Serial again. It shouldn't have errors anymore

Then start cmd+drag to connect your NSPopupButton object

Comment: I think I'm close but upon doing this I get: Failed to connect (serialListPullDown) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSPopUpButtonCell): missing setter or instance variable. Does that mean I still have an extra connection to remove or something like that?

Comment: Make sure you have changed the custom class of the viewcontroller that NSPopupButton object is in. It is the first object under the "View Controller" scene label. The root node of your NSPopupButton in the Interface Builder. Make sure you remove all connections first then reattach again